# how to fix Expo native runtime is not available error in downloaded app from play store?

Tags: javascript, android, expo, react-native

[Image link of crashed report bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ9gB.jpg)

When downloaded the first time, it is working fine. When the app is removed from the background this crash is happening. Please help me in resolving this issue. I don't understand why this happening. But there is not any crash when it is run in development time.